# MySQL 5 - Insert inline HTML content into SQL Column Failing using UPDATE

Tags: html, mysql

Using a MySQL 5 database, I am trying to manually update a field in the database with inline HTML as such:

```
UPDATE employee SET bio =  "<div style="text-align:center"> <H2>Employment History</H2> <table class='table' style="width:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><tr><th>Year</th><th>Company</th></tr><tr><td>2013-14</td><td>IBM</td></tr><tr><td>2015-16</td><td>Microsoft</td></tr><tr><td>2016-17</td><td>Google</td></tr></table><H2>BIO</H2></div><p>John Smith started out as developer and became project manager.</p>" where ID = 100;
```

(by the way, this is not one line - its gets wrapped into multiple lines when I copy / pasted it inside the MySQL Shell)

Results in the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'margin-left:auto' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'margin-right:auto' at line 1
```

What am I possibly doing wrong? Is there a way to just do this change using an HTML file inside an UPDATE or ALTER SQL statement?

Comment: String values should be enclosed with quotes, or much better - you should use prepared statement for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same quotes around the string as you're using around the HTML attributes in the string. You need to use different quotes or escape the inner quotes.

```
UPDATE employee SET bio =  "<div style='text-align:center'> <H2>Employment History</H2> <table class='table' style='width:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'><tr><th>Year</th><th>Company</th></tr><tr><td>2013-14</td><td>IBM</td></tr><tr><td>2015-16</td><td>Microsoft</td></tr><tr><td>2016-17</td><td>Google</td></tr></table><H2>BIO</H2></div><p>John Smith started out as developer and became project manager.</p>" where ID = 100;
```

If you're doing this from a client application language, use a prepared statement instead of substituting directly into the SQL string.

Comment: I am trying to do this using the MySQL shell - no client language. How do I escape double quotes in MySQL?

Comment: Got it working using string literals (double quotes "" for every " and for the single quotes used a backslash like this \'). Thanks for the help, @Barmar.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes if the string is delimited with double quotes.